# Python Mysql Column=Column Doesn't work well

Tags: python, sql, mysql, flask

What I want to achieve is that show all columns, since there won't be a specified condition.If you ask why do you add columns to WHERE condition; the answer is: There are 6 select's in the page and each of them might be chosen or not be chosen. For example, user might want to choose 2 of them and not fill other 4.In this situation, i pass column names instead of a value for those selects.

```
 cursor.execute('Select * from invoices_budgets WHERE year=year AND status=status')
```

This one works.

```
cursor.execute('Select * from invoices_budgets WHERE year=%s AND status=%s',('year','status'))
```

This one doesn't work.
My usual code is:

```
 cursor.execute('Select * from invoices_budgets WHERE year=%s AND status=%s',(year,status))
```

In the above code, year = 'year' and status = 'status'. So the above 2 examples are the same. Is the topmost example using different type than str? or is there any other solution than using column=column.I code in flask, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-strings, i use like that for my queries that need variables:

```
 cursor.execute(f'Select * from invoices_budgets WHERE year={year} AND status={status}')
```

And you need to be sure that your type of status and year are string just before passing to execute method.

```
print(type(year),type(status))
cursor.execute('Select * from invoices_budgets WHERE year=%s AND status=%s',(year,status))
```